# iOS: how to increase chunk size for NSURLSession upload task?

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-upload, nsurlsession

I'm working on a project that requires uploading large files to server. I use NSURLSession for setting up background transfer service. Everything seems to work just fine, however I believe it keeps on sending chunks in 32K. I wonder if there's a way to increase the chunk size?

Here's the sample code for setting up an upload task:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:identifier];
sessionConfig.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1;
NSURLSession *upLoadSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self configureURLRequest];
NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [upLoadSession uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];

[uploadTask resume];
```

Here's the delegate sample code.:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didSendBodyData:(int64_t)bytesSent totalBytesSent:(int64_t)totalBytesSent totalBytesExpectedToSend:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToSend {

DLog(@"didSendBodyData: %lld, totalBytesSent: %lld, totalBytesExpectedToSend: %lld", bytesSent, totalBytesSent, totalBytesExpectedToSend);    

}
```

Again, is there a way to increase chunk size for uploading using NSURLSession? By default it's 32K.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to control the chunk size when using NSURLSession API's. As a side note, you probably don't want to. As the device does things like change from WiFi to cellular, or swap cell towers, your bandwidth will change. I'd expect the OS is constantly adapting to these complex changing variables, reacting by throttling your apps bandwidth. You actually want this, as making a greedy request on a crumby cell network will most likely fail.